# How to add some blur inside a glass sphere and keep the outside sharp & reflective?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

How to add some blur inside a glass sphere and keep the outside sharp & reflective? Blur may not be the right descriptive because there is also some distortion. I'd like to keep it one mesh because I'm going to shatter it and the pieces need the same material.. Here's what I want.

[image: Ref]

Here's what I have.

[image: Current Render]

Node set up.

[image: Nodes]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the roughness of the _Refraction BSDF_ while keeping it low on the _Principled BSDF_?

Comment: @Duane Dibbley - I have but there is some distortion in there that I'm try to achieve as well.

Comment: Perhaps a low density Volume Scatter with anisotropy controlled by a texture, e.g. Noise, Musgrave or Magic. Or using such a texture to control the IOR. Or even combine both ideas. I'm not at my own computer right now, and I can't install Blender to play with it where I am, so I hope you get my ideas without a full answer.

Comment: Couldnt you give the glass material roughness but add some clear coat for sharp reflections?

Comment: @ Duane Dibbley - This really makes a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Blur" is the right word for describing the effect, but the word for the cause of it is "roughness". Roughness simulates a surface that has microscopic bumps on it. Because of these bumps, light refracts with a little bit of randomness, causing a blur.

All you have to do is increase the `roughness` to about 0.1, in your case:

[image: Screenshot]

Roughness will also blur out the reflections. You said that you want the reflections to be sharp. But look carefully at the reference image. The reflections are slightly blurry, too!

Anyway, here is my result of a sphere with the `principled` shader and a bit of roughness:

[image: result]

Note that if you would actually need a sharp reflection, you would have to mix a rough refraction with a smooth glossy shader, controlling the proportion by the Fresnel node. (Or you could use the clearcoat feature in the principled shader). This would not be realistic, though, because usually the roughness for the reflection and refraction is the same – unless there are multiple layers in the material, which does not seem to be the case for a simple glass sphere.

Comment: The reason I I thought blur might not be accurate is that if you look at the reference image there is also some distortion. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your example is a glass sphere with a bubble inside it--perhaps a bubble of air, perhaps a bubble of water or some other material with a different refractive index.

I'm not sure this is the effect you want to recreate, but by mixing two different glass shaders using the fresnel as a mix factor, you can create some cool procedural sphere-within-a-sphere effects:

[image: sphere within a sphere one]

[image: sphere within a sphere two]

[image: sphere within a sphere node setup]

Parameters to play with to vary the effects include the IORs of the two glass shaders, the colors of the two glass shaders, and the color ramp that controls the fresnel.

Top image: inner glass material has IOR of 3 (as shown in the node setup).
Middle image: inner glass material has IOR of 2.